# Изображения в мобильной версии bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, frontend, bootstrap4

Лендинг http://adrenalin-ufa.ru , в секции carousel , в мобильной версии неправильно отображаются изображения ( отображается левая часть , а необходимо , что бы отображался центр или правая часть изображения ) слабо знаком с css , ищу совет как отредактировать стили :

```
.carousel-item > img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left:0;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 40rem;
}
```

и , если это необходимо , отредактировать html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

убрать `left:0`

добавить:

```
  margin-left:50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
```

Comment: большое спасибо, помогло